# translating if to for loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

Hi guys would like to ask help from you on how to convert these following If/else codes to a for loop. 
Here is my code:

```
List<int> PrimeBuilders = new List<int>();
int Input;
void OnNextBuild()
{
    int Temp = PrimeBuilders.Count;

    if(Temp == 2)
    {
      if(Input == PrimeBuilders[0])
        {
            do this
        }

        else if(input == PrimeBuilders[1])
        {
             do this
        }           
    }       

    else if(Temp == 3)
    {
      if(Input == PrimeBuilders[0])
        {
            do this
        }

        else if(input == PrimeBuilders[1])
        {
             do this
        }

        else if(input == PrimeBuilders[2])
        {
             do this
        }           
    }
   if(Temp == 4)
    {
        if(Input == PrimeBuilders[0])
        {
            do this
        }

        else if(input == PrimeBuilders[1])
        {
             do this
        }   

        else if(input == PrimeBuilders[2])
        {
             do this
        }

        else if(input == PrimeBuilders[3])
        {
             do this
        }       
    }

}
```

i wanted to make a for loop that would first check for the size of temp and then hopefuly make another loop to check if _building_instance.BuildingID is in the List. Then runs the code when it gets the match.

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: Nobody wants to go through all your code. Post only relevant code, preferably http://sscce.org/

Comment: please see simplified code. thanks

Comment: @user1998735 if all you want to do is `do this` why even use `if`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you're trying to do but your logic can be simplified to something like this:

```
void OnNextBuild()
{
  if (PrimeBuilders.Count < 2) return;
  int i = PrimeBuilders.IndexOf(_building_instance.BuildingID);

  if(i != -1)
  {
      if(++i == PrimeBuilders.Count) i = 0;
      _building_instance = _simulation_manager.
                            GetCity().
                            GetBuildingInstance(PrimeBuilders[i]);

      _interface_state_manager.SetNextState(InterfaceState.ShowBuildUnitsPanel);
  }
}
```